# Windows Server 2008 R2 Firewall -- Block ICMP except specific IPs

Tags: windows-firewall

this is half a minute work with any firewall, but with the built-in firewall on Windows 2008 R2, I am stuck here for half an hour.

I want to block all incoming ICMP requests to my server, EXCEPT those IP addresses that I want. My firewall policy is to "Block all inbound requests that do not satisfy a rule"

**1st attempt:**
I create an allow rule for only those IPs that I want. The firewall should allow only those and block all others.  *Result: **It allows everything**.*

**2nd attempt**
I create a Block rule for ICMP and for Any IP.
Then I keep the same Allow rule as in 1st attempt.
*Result: **It blocks everything**.*

What am I missing here ?

**Update:**

OK. I give up. The only thing that I can do is to Block all addresses using as scope those ranges that leave out all the IPs that I want to be allowed.

For example if I want to allow IP 100.100.100.100
is set the scope:

1. from 0.0.0.0 to 100.100.100.99
2. from 100.100.100.101 to 255.255.255.255

I wish there was another way.

Comment: Block ICMP echo if you _really_ must (it won't secure your systems BTW!), but I'd suggest you don't block all [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) packets.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bryan. However this does not answer my question

Comment: exactly why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

No need to create a rule from scratch.  There should be a rule called File and Printer Sharing (ICMPv4).  Enable this and lock down to IPs you want.

EDIT:  Make sure that you edit the correct version of firewall.  I.E. Domain, if you connected to a domain etc.

Comment: nope. everyone can connect, even though I restricted to the IPs that I wanted.

Comment: That means that there is another rule that is enabled that is overriding your denies.  Allows trump denies in the 2008 firewall.